# Learning socket.io before Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to network apps on iOS and I heard a great way to accomplish this is through Socket.io. The functionality that I am looking for would be more chat/posting functionality. I have almost no knowledge of JavaScript or anything about Socket.io (or server sockets at all for that matter). How do I approach learning Socket.io with no prior knowledge of Javascript? or should I try something else? I do not think it would be time-efficient to learn Javascript for web development because I am trying to develop only for iOS.
I really appreciate all help!

Comment: What behaviors do you want out of the apps? How they interact may impact the tool I'd suggest you use. Socket.io is great, but may not be what you need.

Comment: I am looking for chat functionality or posting functionality @dbburgess

Comment: Ah, well I think socket.io definitely would be good for that, and while I don't think the learning curve is super high, you may consider using a hosted service such as [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) or [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) that will do a similar job without you having to learn JavaScript to use it.

Comment: So, how  do I apply javascript knowledge to this situation? Like in my mind there is not connection between Javascript and Swift code for my app @dbburgess

Comment: There's not. That's why I suggested maybe using a different backend that will do a similar job, so you don't need to use a tool and language you are unfamiliar with. If you're dead-set on using Socket.io, there are ways to run Javascript code, but I'd imagine it'd be fraught with peril, especially given you don't have much JS experience.

Comment: Another possible solution would be to use a library that interacts with Socket.io that doesn't require Javascript, such as [Socket.IO-Client-Swift](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift). I've not used that, but it looks like a pretty good / well supported library for using Socket.io is Swift.

Comment: I have tried that but I am not really understanding the class system and there is no API to regard when trying to learn it. @dbburgess